# My docker image in google cloud run doesn't read css file

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-run, django-staticfiles

I create my website with Django composed with docker.

When I compile this docker image, the app shows a webpage with CSS, on the other hand when I deploy this docker image on the google cloud run then it shows only HTML file, I mean it doesn't include CSS file so that it shows just text.

Does anyone know why this happened?
If someone knows, please let me know the ways to show my website with styles.

Comment: Did you remember to run collectstatic when the container is initialized and configure your server to point to the static dir?

Comment: I don’t know that. Is to running collectstatic necessary? Because in local environment the docker shows the website correctly. 
Sorry if I had ridiculous question, because I’m new of this.

Answer (score 4):

`collectstatic` is necessary in production, but not in development. The idea is to create a static folder at the root of your project that nginx (or whatever server you're using) can access it directly. When using `Docker`, a common approach is to include an entrypoint.

To do this, add the following to your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV APP_HOME=/code # replace with your container's root dir
COPY ./entrypoint.sh $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`entrypoint.sh` would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# python entry point commands go here
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

exec "$@"
```

Also make sure you have something like

```
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

in your `settings.py`

The rest depends on your server settings (nginx, apache or whatever you're using) but might look something like

```
location /static/ {
    root /code/static/;
    autoindex off;
}
```

in nginx.

One tool I find incredibly useful is [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). Just follow the setup guide, and you'll be able to skip the nginx stuff.

Comment: Ok. I'm not good at server settings then I will follow whitenoise tutorial because you said I'm able to skip the nginx stuff.

Comment: whitenoise set up guide worked for my environment without nginx knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the set up in [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) that John Kealy mentioned.

set setting.py file like below.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ...
]
```

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/" #the folder name you want
```

Then command below in python interpreter. Or write this in Dockerfile as John described.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

Then deploy the image.